# Laravel Password Manager decrypt Passwords

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, passwords

I want to program a password manager with Laravel. But I don't understand how I can output the passwords from the individual pages back in string form. If you use the bcrypt function of Laravel, you can't display the original text again. I really want to store all passwords in hashed form in the database. Nothing should be in plain text.

Does anyone have experience or an idea how to realize this?

Comment: Why do you want to decrypt the passwords?  Using password_hash and password_verify allows you to properly store and check passwords without decoding them.

Comment: @NigelRen I want to store my Passwords for other Websites like Gmail, Facebook, .... and I need to see them in String-Form so i can copy them

Comment: `bcrypt` is a hashing algorithm, not an `encryption` algorithm. Hashes are designed to be one way. You would need to use one of the `encryption` features in Laravel to do what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

You can't decrypt a hash, but you can encrypt/decrypt your "passwords" into a separate database column.

```php
// import the namespace
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

Crypt::encryptString('string to encrypt');
```

and to decrypt the encrypted string use

```php
// import the namespace
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

Crypt::decryptString('encrypted string here');
```

It uses your `APP_KEY` from `.env` to encrypt and decrypt. You can read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption)